# Use a foreach in 2 places php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I was trying to get the same result in two places with this code by including it with include(""); but after the first include goes right the second one gives me the  last element of the array I made, the array is this one:

```
<?php
$aMenu = array(
    array( 
        "title" => "Home",
        "page" => "home",
    ),
    array(
        "title" => "Over mijzelf",
        "page" => "mijzelf",
    ),
    array(
        "title" => "PC Games",
        "page" => "games",
    ),
    array(
        "title" => "Video's maken",
        "page" => "videos",
    ),
    array(
        "title" => "Basketball",
        "page" => "basketball",
    ),
    array(
        "title" => "Fitness",
        "page" => "fitness"
    ),
    array(
        "title" => "Toekomst",
        "page" => "toekomst"
    ),
);
```

---

I call it here

```
foreach($aMenu as $aMenu) {
    $sClass =  '';
    if ($aMenu["page"] == $_GET['page']) {
        $sClass = 'class = "active" ';
    }

    /*echo $aMenu["title"];
    echo $aMenu["page"];*/

    echo '
        <ul  class=" nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li class="'.$sClass.'" role="presentation"  ><a href="index.php?page='.$aMenu["page"].'">'.$aMenu["title"].'</a></li>
        </ul>'; 
}
```

Comment: <?php 
foreach($aMenu as $aMenu)
      {
       $sClass= '';
       if($aMenu["page"] == $_GET['page'] ) :
        $sClass = ' class="active" ';
       endif;
       /*echo $aMenu["title"];
       echo $aMenu["page"];*/
       
       echo '
       <ul  class=" nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
       <li class="'.$sClass.'" role="presentation"  ><a href="index.php?page='.$aMenu["page"].'">'.$aMenu["title"].'</a></li>
       </ul>'; 
      }
?>

Comment: This one is the call i couldnt write everything and after i call it i include it to html with <?php............... ?>

Comment: Your comment should be part of your question

Comment: And you want to repeat the same loop somewhere else on the page?

Comment: yeah i have the menu on the left side and i want to call the same menu for the footer. but i keep getting the last element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You overwrite your array while iterating:

```
foreach($aMenu as $aMenu)
```

Write something like this

```
foreach($aMenu as $entry)
```

so your iteration variable won't overwrite the array itself.

Comment: Thx for the help it helped me alot